# can x86 intel 32-bit assembly do actions over a wireless network?

Tags: windows, networking, assembly, x86, intel

I have been searching for assembly documentation and have come across the documentation released by Intel in their processor manuals, and it has a section in it relating to the I/O aspect of the processor. And that got me intrigued as to whether assembly can access even more than that, such as sending information to another computer over a wireless network, or network in general. I am currently using Windows XP, and the reason for asking this question is that I want create a chatroom-type program that allows two users to send messages to each other over a wireless network. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Just disassemble a wireless driver and you see assembly code which does something over the wireless.

Comment: You don't want to write a chat room in assembly! It will spend most of its time waiting for the user to type the next character.

Comment: Why would it do that? And apart from trying to create a chatroom, how would one send information over a network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your assembly program you can call some network library or call a syscall to send a TCP packet for example (using linux you can open a /dev/tcp// file and write/read as a file).

Or you can interact over the driver directly if the operational system permit

Comment: How can I call a syscall or interact with the driver?

Comment: I am currently using Windows XP, and the reason for asking this question is that I want create a chatroom-type program that allows two users to send messages to each other over a wireless network. Is this possible?

Comment: @Progrmr: Yes it is possible. Generally speaking, everything you can do in any computer language is possible in assembly. Thats because everything a computer does boils down to executing machine code instructions on your processor and the the machine code has a one to one representation as assembly.

Comment: http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/x86assembly/ in powers.asm you have an example with printf called

Answer (score 1):

Assembly language is just a human readable representation of what understands and can do the CPU. If the CPU is connected to I/O devices and there are all the necessary I/O drivers, the CPU can perform I/O with them. Of course, those drivers are hardware- and OS-specific.

W.r.t. the wording, assembly language cannot do anything. It's an abstract thing.

Comment: Can you provide code to show me (I have no idea how to do this, and also there are essentially no internet resources/documentation)?